# how to extract a tree iteration in C++

Tags: c++, tree

I've been repeating a chunk of similar code for several times. This how it's like in pseudo code:

```
stack.push(root)
while stack size > 0
  node = stack.pop()
  if condition_1
    if node is leaf
      if condition_2
        // do something,
        // for example, push node into a vector and return the vector
    else
      stack.push(children of node)
```

or like this:

```
stack.push(root)
while stack size > 0
  node = stack.pop()
  if condition_1
    if node is leaf
      if condition_2 // or no condition_2 and return true directly
        return true
    else
      stack.push(children of node)
return false
```

The difference between this two snippets is that the first one iterates all leaf nodes, while the second one has a break logic. And usually the main work I do is `condition_2` and what's in its scope. Other lines are just repeating themselves.

So is there a way to extract this kind of tree iterating loop, in C++ or any other language?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "extract"?

Comment: The visitor pattern can be used for this: [Visitor pattern where the visitors choose how to traverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565781/visitor-pattern-where-the-visitors-choose-how-to-traverse)

Answer (score 1):

As I understood correctly, you want to have a generic version of this algorithm.

I don't know which parts you do want to make generic, so here is a very simple solution where everything is generic.

```cpp
template <class NodeType, class TraversalPredicate, class LeafPredicate,
          class TerminalPredicate, class ChildrenGetter>
bool findIf(NodeType *root, TraversalPredicate shouldTraverse,
            LeafPredicate isLeaf, TerminalPredicate shouldFinish,
            ChildrenGetter getChildren) {
  std::stack<NodeType *> stack;
  stack.push(root);

  while (not stack.empty()) {
    auto *node = stack.top();
    stack.pop();
    if (not shouldTraverse(node))
      continue;

    if (isLeaf(node)) {
      if (shouldFinish(node)) {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      for (auto *child : getChildren(node)) {
        stack.push(child);
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I hope that is what you were looking for!